# Select a string comparison as a boolean in tsql

Tags: t-sql

In a tsql query, I want to have a calculated field that is the boolean result of a string comparison.

It would look something like this:

```
select name, (status = 'current') as IsValid
from items
```

But the query as I have listed is not valid. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use a case statement

```
Select name, case when status = 'current' then 1 else 0 end as IsValid
from items
```

Comment: beat me to it. just a few seconds ;)

Comment: @Epotter - note that your "bool" you asked for is (correctly) represented in TSQL as a "bit,", i.e., 1 or 0. So test against a bit in your downstream code.

Comment: @Sachin, I might have had a few second advantage from using the approach earlier this morning ;) @SethO, solid comment, bit as boolean isn't necessarily obvious, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```
select name, 
(CASE status WHEN 'current' THEN 1 Else 0 END) as IsValid 
from items
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, IIF(status = 'current', 1, 0) as IsValid
from items
```